# Why isn't `auto-remove' removing all unnecessary dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I just installed a package (`dansguardian` in this case) and `apt` told me that I had unmet dependencies.

```
# sudo apt-get install dansguardian
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  clamav clamav-base clamav-freshclam libclamav6 libtommath0
Suggested packages:
  clamav-docs squid libclamunrar6
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  clamav clamav-base clamav-freshclam dansguardian libclamav6 libtommath0
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4,956 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

So I installed it and the dependencies. So far so good.

Later on, I decide that this package just isn't the package for me, so I want to remove it and all of the other junk it installed with it since I'm not going to be needing any of it:

```
# sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove --purge dansguardian
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  dansguardian
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1,816 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

However it is only removing that one specific package. What about `clamav clamav-base clamav-freshclam libclamav6 libtommath0`? Not only did it not remove them, but `clamav` was actually running a daemon that loads every time the computer boots. I thought that `--auto-remove` would remove not only the packages, but also the dependencies that were installed with it.

So basically, without going through the `apt` history log file (if I even remember to do so, or if I even remember that a specific package I installed 3 months ago had dependencies along with it), is there a way to remove a package and all of the other dependencies that were installed like in this case?

Comment: Can you still remove other packages with dependencies with `--auto-remove` switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As izx said, in his general answer, the first point, can be the cause of this sort of things.

> Those dependencies are now also required/recommended by some other package(s) which are still installed on your system.

This is the most probable and valid reason for this *kind* of situation,But I am thinking that, the other packages named with `clamav clamav-base clamav-freshclam libclamav6 libtommath0` most likely only associated with their mother package `clamav`. So, the first point, may not be the case in this *particular* situation.

The most likely cause of this problem, which seems to be the cause is, after installing the `dansguardian` package, you later installed all it's dependency packages by doing this kind of command below:

```
sudo apt-get install clamav clamav-base clamav-freshclam dansguardian libclamav6 libtommath0
```

If this is indeed the case, you can't uninstalled them by removing their mother package `dansguardian`. since in APT's language, they are installed "manually" as you explicitly installed these packages by feeding their name to the `apt-get` command, so ***must*** also uninstall them with explicitly stating their package name

You can check this, if it is the case by viewing `/var/log/apt/history.log` files.

#### To remove:

You must remove the installed packages by explicitly naming their name.So, in your specific situation it is

```
sudo apt-get purge clamav clamav-base clamav-freshclam dansguardian libclamav6 libtommath0
```

#### To see the dependent packages

You can find all the dependent packages with the below command:

```
apt-cache depends -i dansguardian | cut -f 2 -d ':' | tr '\n' ' '.
```

**Note** that, `dansguardian` depends on package `libc6`. while that package is very very essential one in your system. So, you can't remove all the dependency of `dansguardian` by generating their dependency package list with `apt-cache` command, hence it is not recommended. *(actually, it is highly recommended to avoid doing that, unless you are happy with a broken system)*

Comment: `depends` also shows suggests, etc. so I'd suggest filtering for "Depends" before piping to cut, etc. :)   Good answer.

Comment: @izx Thanks, i think it shows dependent and recommended packages, but not suggested packages. and the  default policy of APT in Ubuntu is to consider recommended packages as dependency, as far as i know ,Apt does not install suggested packages

Comment: Please see [this paste](https://gist.github.com/2981648). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @izx, i was wrong in telling that, "it shows only deps and recommends" while i was willing to tell "apt-get only install deps and recommends". just mixing the things. *(may be cause of yesterdays' bad sleep)*. very very thanks. I will update the answer

Comment: Anwar - you're not wrong, apt is "lying" --- what "depends" shows as "suggests" are actually "recommends!" - so make sure the answer reflects that.

Comment: @izx, thanks again. is the last edit correct?. is this behavior of "apt-cache" is only in this specific package?. Normally, apt-cache is a very honest person.

Comment: I have a feeling that this might be what happened since the first time I installed it, I used Synaptic. So I would assume that synaptic would have installed everything including the dependencies all in one shot instead of simply installing the package I want, and saying "yes" when prompted for dependencies. Then when I later uninstalled everything and reinstalled it just to see what would happen, it wouldn't remove the dependencies since they were marked as being manually installed once upon a time.

Answer (score 3):

#### Specific answer:

This is not normal behavior:

```
izx@preciseunity:~$ sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove --purge dansguardian
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  clamav* clamav-base* clamav-freshclam* dansguardian* libclamav6*
  libtommath0* python-gpgme*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 7 to remove and 91 not upgraded.
After this operation, 14.7 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

See general answer no. 1 below for the most probable reason why.

---

#### General answer:

This can happen for multiple reasons. The most common ones are:

1. Those dependencies are now also required/recommended by some other package(s) which are still installed on your system.
2. The original package was a meta-package, i.e. a shortcut to install multiple packages in one swift stroke. Removing a metapackage only removes the shortcut itself, not all the packages it installed. Common examples are the various umbrella desktop packages, eg *ubuntu-desktop*.

**To remove**, use `apt-cache depends package-name` to get its dependencies, and feed those to `apt-get remove`. Double check the list shown to make sure you don't lose anything important!

You can do this in one step with the following command (again, don't press Y unless you've read the list!):

```
sudo apt-get remove `apt-cache depends dansguardian | grep Dep | cut -d: -f2 | tr '\n' ' '`
```

Comment: but i thought a metapackage should not be of that big size. Yes, first point is very good